# Is it faster to delete properties or construct a new object with only desired properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, properties

I have a loop being executed several million times, in NodeJS, that amongst many other things strips a few undesired properties from some objects.

I'm curious to know in general, whether it is faster to do:

```
undesiredPropsArray.forEach(p => delete(obj[p]))
```

or

```
var newObj = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(p => { if (!undesiredPropsObj[p]) newObj[p] = obj[p] });
```

Simply running a test isn't as simple as it sounds maybe, because the number of desired and undesired properties will vary.

Comment: In general the standard says nothing about what should be faster. That means it's implementation dependent, and also means, that every other runtime version can change it.

Comment: Lodash has a fn that does this and the lib is pretty performance centric. I'd check out the source for it get ideas. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick

Answer (score 1):

If you, for a moment, assume that each of those commands take equal time to execute, then whichever task has less commands to execute will execute faster. In other words, if you have less undesired properties, compared to number of properties that you want to keep, then deleting should be faster (and vice-versa). Although, unless we're talking about huge objects processed a huge number of times, the time saved will be negligent. I think :)

Answer (score 1):

You can benchmark and compare javascript code on [jsperf](https://jsperf.com). I did and first approach is faster as expected (aprox by 66% - this may vary)..

EDIT: 
This is init code I used:

```
  var undesiredPropsArray = [];
  var undesiredPropsObj = {};
  var obj = {};

  for (i=0;i<10000;i++) {
    obj[i] = null;
    if ((i%2) === 0) {
        undesiredPropsArray.push(i);
        undesiredPropsObj[i] = null;
    }
  }
```